# Tic tac toe- What's the mistake here

Tags: python

WHAT'S THE MISTAKE HERE??

```
Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-51-cb088c4c5c82> in <module>
     17             display_board(the_board)
     18             position = player_choice(the_board)
---> 19             place_marker(the_board,Player1_marker,position)
     20             if win_check(the_board,Player1_marker):
     21                 display_board(the_board)

<ipython-input-41-ba563e2cb168> in place_marker(board, marker, position)
      1 def place_marker(board, marker, position):
----> 2     board[position] = marker

TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not NoneType
```

Comment: We can't help you debug code we don't have access to.

Comment: You'll need to show us your code and error mate

Comment: Apparently, `position` is `None`, which isn't a valid index. We'd need to see `player_choice`

Answer (score 0):

The lines shown state *exactly* what is wrong, and where. You just need to know how to interpret it:

```
     18             position = player_choice(the_board)
---> 19             place_marker(the_board,Player1_marker,position)

      1 def place_marker(board, marker, position):
----> 2     board[position] = marker

TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not NoneType
```

What you can glean from all that is that:

- the `position` variable used in line 2 of `place_marker()` is set to `None` since that is the *actual* error (variables set to `None` are of the type `NoneType`, and `position` is the list index being complained about);
- that `position` variable is initialised from a variable of the same name, as part of the call to `place_marker()` on line 19, so it too must also be set to `None`;
- that variable (the one passed in) came from the function `player_choice()`.

In other words, your line:

```
position = player_choice(the_board)
```

has returned `None` for some reason.

Unfortunately, since you haven't shown us that *code* for that function, we can't really dive any deeper into the analysis, but you *may* want to look for paths in that function that return *without* a value. This is a typical cause of functions returning `None`, such as with:

```
def fn(x):
    if x == 1:
        return 7 # This path returns 7 when 1 is passed in.
    # This path returns None (implicitly) for any other value.

print(fn(1)) # Explicitly gets 7.
print(fn(2)) # Implicitly gets None.
```

The result of running that code is, as per the comments:

```
7
None
```